# How to determine whether a unicode character is fullwidth or halfwidth in Perl

Tags: perl, unicode

How can I determine in Perl, whether a unicode character is a full width (taking two cells; double width) one or half-width (as usual latin characters) one?

E.g. Emoji-s are of double width, but there are also characters in lower blocks such as `"\N{MEDIUM BLACK CIRCLE}"` (U+26ab).

I tried

```
Unicode::GCString->new("\N{LARGE RED CIRCLE}")->columns()
```

but it also returns 1.

Comment: You can file a bugreport at the [Unicode-LineBreak](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Unicode-LineBreak) distribution bugtracker.

Comment: The UCD used to define the U+26AB as [N]arrow, but it now classifies it at a [W]ide. Perhaps Unicode::GCString is using an outdated version of the database?

Comment: yeah, if I understand correctly, Unicode::LineBreak uses version 8 of the UCD, but U+26AB was made wide in version 9. (Version 15 is the latest.)

Comment: [Bug report](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=140863)

Answer (score 5):

I have some C++ code lying around to calculate character widths. So, a quick conversion to perl later, and...

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/state/;
use open qw/:std :locale/;
use charnames qw/:full/;
use Unicode::UCD qw/charinfo charprop/;

# Return the number of fixed-width columns taken up by a unicode codepoint
# Inspired by https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/wcwidth.c
# First adapted to use C++/ICU functions and then to perl
sub charwidth ($) {
  state %cache;

  my $cp = shift; # Numeric codepoint
  return $cache{$cp} if exists $cache{$cp};

  if ($cp == 0 || $cp == 0x200B) {
    # nul and ZERO WIDTH SPACE
    $cache{$cp} = 0;
    return 0;
  } elsif ($cp >= 0x1160 && $cp <= 0x11FF) {
    # Hangul Jamo vowels and final consonants
    $cache{$cp} = 0;
    return 0;
  } elsif ($cp == 0xAD) {
    # SOFT HYPHEN
    $cache{$cp} = 1;
    return 1;
  }

  my $ci = charinfo($cp);
  return undef unless defined $ci;

  my $type = $ci->{category};
  if ($type eq "Cc" || $type eq "Mn" || $type eq "Me" || $type eq "Cf") {
    # Control Code, Non Spacing Mark, Enclosing Mark, Format Char
    $cache{$cp} = 0;
    return 0;
  }

  state $widths = { Fullwidth => 2, Wide => 2, Halfwidth => 1, Narrow => 1,
                    Neutral => 1, Ambiguous => 1 };
  my $eaw = charprop($cp, "East_Asian_Width");
  my $width = $widths->{$eaw} // 1;
  $cache{$cp} = $width;
  return $width;
}

sub testwidth ($) {
  my $char = shift;
  my $cp = ord $char;
  printf "Width of %c (U+%04X %s) is %d\n", $cp, $cp, charnames::viacode($cp),
    charwidth($cp);
}

testwidth "\x04";
testwidth "a";
testwidth "\N{MEDIUM BLACK CIRCLE}";
testwidth "\N{LARGE RED CIRCLE}";
testwidth "\N{U+20A9}";
testwidth "\N{U+1F637}";
```

Example use:

```sh
$ ./charwidths.pl
Width of  (U+0004 END OF TRANSMISSION) is 0
Width of a (U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A) is 1
Width of ⚫ (U+26AB MEDIUM BLACK CIRCLE) is 2
Width of  (U+1F534 LARGE RED CIRCLE) is 2
Width of ₩ (U+20A9 WON SIGN) is 1
Width of  (U+1F637 FACE WITH MEDICAL MASK) is 2
```

It just does some special-case checks of particular ranges and categories of codepoints, and then uses the East Asian Width property along with recommendations from [TR11](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr11/) to determine width of everything else.

Comment: That cache can grow quite big! A much better data structure could be used, especially since neighbours usually have the same width. In fact, I suspect that a very small data structure could be used to incorporate all the data. Small enough that you could actually build the entire thing once.

Comment: @ikegami I'm working on some code that can map and merge invlists/invmaps as used by Unicode::UCD (I think I've got it working but it's a bit messy and unwieldy for a SO post). The final result is a 909-element array that can be binary-searched over using search_invlist.

Answer (score 4):

This is a little messy and I'm hesitant to launch it onto the internet without cleaning it up into a proper library... but I'm unlikely to ever *have the time* to make that library, so here it is in case it's useful. It's very much derived from [Shawn's contribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70836895/152948) but instead of using a per-codepoint "cache" that could grow to millions of entries, it uses the Unicode::UCD data to build an "invmap" of codepoint ranges and their associated widths on first call; querying that map works like (and costs the same as or slightly less than) a single `charprop` call.

`map_im` takes an invmap as returned by `prop_invmap` and maps the property values through a hash. Any value not found in the hash will become an `undef`, which isn't used by Unicode::UCD, but is treated by our code as a "don't care". `merge_im` takes two such invmaps and merges them such that values in the "right" invmap override values in the "left" invmap, but undef ranges on the right side allow the left-side values to "shine through". `charwidth`'s state initialization maps and merges three invmaps (those for East_Asian_Width, Category, and a special-case override list) according to the logic from Shawn's own `charwidth`, and the function simply queries that using Unicode::UCD's own `search_invlist` routine.

The initialization takes <60ms on my laptop and produces a 909-element invmap (using the UCD from perl 5.32.1), and querying takes about 2.5us per call afterwards.

```perl
use Unicode::UCD;
use open qw/:std :locale/;
use charnames qw/:full/;
use feature 'state';
use List::Util 'reduce';

sub map_im {
  my ($im, $h) = @_;
  die unless $im->[2] eq 's';

  my $out;

  for my $i (0 .. $#{ $im->[0] }) {
    my $val = $h->{ $im->[1][$i] };

    my $different = @{ $out->[0] } ? ($val ne $out->[1][-1]) : defined($val);
    if ($different) {
      push @{ $out->[0] }, $im->[0][$i];
      push @{ $out->[1] }, $val;
    }
  }

  return $out;
}

sub merge_im {
  my ($l, $r) = @_;
  die unless $l->[0][0] == 0;

  my $out;
  my $idx_l = my $idx_r = 0;
  my $val_l = $l->[1][0];
  my $val_r;

  while ($idx_r < @{ $r->[0] } || $idx_l < @{ $l->[0] }) {
    my $newcp;
    # Take from the list with the lower next entry. Or the one with entries left.
    # This could probably be simplified.
    if ($idx_r >= @{ $r->[0] } || ($idx_l < @{ $l->[0] } 
        && $l->[0][$idx_l] <= $r->[0][$idx_r])) {
      $newcp = $l->[0][$idx_l];
      $val_l = $l->[1][$idx_l];
      $idx_l ++;
    } else {
      $newcp = $r->[0][$idx_r];
      $val_r = $r->[1][$idx_r];
      $idx_r ++;
    }

    # But if they both have a transition at the same codepoint, take both so there's
    # not a duplicate.
    if ($idx_r < @{ $r->[0] } && $r->[0][$idx_r] == $newcp) {
      $val_r = $r->[1][$idx_r];
      $idx_r ++;
    }

    my $newval = defined($val_r) ? $val_r : $val_l;
    # This gets skipped if we updated $val_l but $val_r is overriding, or
    # $val_r went from undef to equaling $val_l.
    if ($newval ne $out->[1][-1]) {
      push @{ $out->[0] }, $newcp;
      push @{ $out->[1] }, $newval;
    }
  }

  return $out;
}

sub charwidth {
  state $width_eaw = map_im([Unicode::UCD::prop_invmap('East_Asian_Width')], 
    { F => 2, W => 2, H => 1, Na => 1, Neutral => 1, A => 1 }
  );

  state $width_cat = map_im([Unicode::UCD::prop_invmap('Category')],
    { Cc => 0, Mn => 0, Me => 0, Cf => 0 }
  );

  state $width_override = [
    [ 0x0000, 0x0001, # NUL
      0x00AD, 0x00AE, # Soft Hyphen
      0x1160, 0x1200, # Hangul Jamo vowels and final consonants
      0x200B, 0x200C, # ZWSP
    ],
    [ 0, undef,
      1, undef,
      0, undef,
      0, undef,
    ],
  ];

  state $merged = reduce { merge_im($a, $b) } $width_eaw, $width_cat, $width_override;

  my $cp = shift;
  my $idx = Unicode::UCD::search_invlist($merged->[0], $cp);
  return $merged->[1][$idx];
}

sub testwidth($) {
  my $char = shift;
  my $cp = ord $char;
  printf "Width of %c (U+%04X %s) is %d\n", $cp, $cp,
     charnames::viacode($cp), charwidth($cp);
}

testwidth "\x04";
testwidth "a";
testwidth "\N{MEDIUM BLACK CIRCLE}";
testwidth "\N{LARGE RED CIRCLE}";
testwidth "\N{U+20A9}";
testwidth "\N{U+1F637}";
```

Comment: Re "*using the UCD from perl 5.32.1*", Version 13.0.0